# How to generate random vallues in excel for arrival and service, with fixed mean?

Tags: excel, random

i am simulating an M/M/1 queue in excel where i want to generate random values for arrival rate lambda and service rate (meu) in two columns such that :

```
    arrival rate (lambda) = 2
    service rate (meu) = 5 (but the average of meu always remains 1 in the column despite      
    generating the values for meu randomly using rand().
```

How can i generate random values using rand() for lambda and meu such that their averages can be restricted to a fixed value in the respective columns. I need to run the simulation for different values of utilization where utilization =  lambda/meu ratio (i need to use 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 and 0.8 for lambda/meu). But the values in the column for both would be random and average of meu should be fixed at 1. I will change lambda for different utilization ratios then.

Comment: What type of distribution do you want to sample from?   What SD do you want to use?

Comment: lamda is the arrival rate and interarrival times (1/lambda) are exponentially distributed). Service time given by 1/meu is also exponentially distributed. I want to simulate the queue for different values of lambda/meu and then calculate the confidence intervals, mean and SD for the queue occupancy for each lambda/meu value.

Comment: basically, i want to implement a queuing system in excel as a discrete event simulation. I need random values for arrival and service rates for this but need to restrict the overall value for service rate meu to one. Is it possible to do this somehow, a customer arrival and service system is what i want to implement and calculate the mean queue size of customers for different arrival and service rates.

Comment: You can generate samples from a normal distribution using `NORMINV(RAND(),[mean],[SD])`. Substitute the desired [mean] and [SD].

Comment: but the distribution isnt normal. Cant i scale the values...i need a set of values for each run (like about 100) so cant i scale them or something. I dont know what SD to fix. I just know that i can fix the mean to 1.

Comment: Can a queuing system be simulated using the normal distribution. I am simulating an M/M/1 queue.

Comment: By definition an M/M/1 is based on exponential distributions for the arrival and service processes.

Answer (score 0):

Excel lacks an exponential RV generating function, but you can generate your own with the desired rate via inversion:  `-log(U) / rate` has an exponential distribution, where `U` is a uniform(0,1) random value and `rate` is the desired rate (mu or lambda).

That said, I really wouldn't recommend using Excel for anything other than toy problems unless you've read papers such as [this one](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~gmelard/rech/gmelard_csda23.pdf) and understand the issues you may be dealing with.

As an aside in case you haven't seen it before, there's an [easy way to model a first-come-first-served single-server queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41101/first-come-first-serve-job-scheduling-algorithm/41175#41175) using iterative logic.